# Using after_find callback to overwrite the field values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have rails 2.3.11. i want to overwrite one of the database field value.But its not overwrite.

```
def after_find
  add_public_uri
end

def add_public_uri
  self.uri = uri.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the syntax, but have you tried

```
after_find: add_public_uri

private
def add_public_uri
  self.uri = uri.to_s
end
```

Alternatively, you could simply have a customer reader in your model:

```
def uri
  uri.to_s
end
```